# android gradle error when updating to sdk 28

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I have an error in the independencies in the module app, from the build gradle in this part when I updated the sdk version from 27 to 28.

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

It throws this error:

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined

I don't want to migrate to androidx, so i need to fix this problem in order to the build gradle work well.

This is the module app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

and this is the build.gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }}
```

Comment: the dependencies you are showing...are they all ? I don't see any androidx dependencies.... so this error should not occur

Comment: I have some firebase dependencies too, but when I deleted that dependencies the error continued

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few lines of code that android studio suggested and it worked

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Comment: I was going to ask you to do that... for some cases, android studio tells you do do some step by step for the solution. carry on